# The "survival hypothesis" and supersymmetry

Tags: supersymmetry, higgs, fine-tuning

Tidying up my old papers I came across my supersymmetry notes from the late 80s. I thought I'd reread them. They may be out of date now. I find the mathematics somewhat comprehensible but not the physical discussion. (Roughly speaking I was a pure mathematician who took courses in QFT and Strings.) Here's a section:

> The hierarchy problem exists because of a basic principle of life the
> universe and everything that goes by many names: Murphy's law, anythng
> that *can go wrong will, or the "survival hypothesis". The scale of
> the breakdown of $SU(2)\times U(1)\rightarrow U(1)$ is (essentially)
> set by the mass of the "Higgs" boson, $m_H$. Any attempt to introduce
> gravity brings in the much higher Planck mass $M_{Pl} (10^{19}GeV)$.
> As a result $m_H$ is usually subject to radiative corrections
> $$ \Delta_H \sim m_{Pl} $$
> Therefore the natural scale for the Higgs
> boson is the Planck scale. In principle we could "fine tune" the
> parameters at our disposal to arrange for $$ m_H \ll m_{Pl} $$ But
> this would violate the above mentioned principle. Unless there is a
> good reason for some particle to "survive" in our low energy world, it
> won't. In a supersymmetric theory, however, we find that
> $$ \Delta m_H=0 $$

Could someone explain what is meant by "survival" and the use of Murphy's law here?

Comment: I don't know why somebody would have written a paper in the 1980s about the Higgs being "natural" at the Planck scale. The people who built LHC (and that was an awful lot of them) knew exactly where to look for the Higgs (below the 1TeV scale). Fermilab was desperately searching for the Higgs and it was just shy of a discovery, if I remember correctly, even though it's a much smaller facility than LHC. Maybe you want to give an actual reference to that paper? It doesn't seem to make any sense to me, just based on actual science history (I was there).

Comment: These aren't a published paper, they are from my old handwritten notes taken in lectures. (95% sure the lecturer was Paul Townsend.) That Planck scale stuff really stands out to me as weird now but at the time I didn't know enough to think anything of it.

Comment: I see. Yeah... I can't quite follow the reasoning. Every theorist I knew who was working on LHC was talking about the Higgs being "natural" in or just slightly outside of the LHC energy window, which is 1TeV by design. I think there were even a bunch of folks who called it almost down to the error bars based on argument from other measurements (but I am not a theorist and I don't remember how they were calculating it).